# Spring @PathVariable get everything after /

Tags: spring-boot, path-variables

I have some url of type: `"/something/some/random/path"`

For all urls that start with `"/something/"` I want everything after it to be considered as a path variable

```
@RequestMapping("/something/{path}")
public MyCustomObj get(@PathVariable("path") String path){
    System.out.println(path); // "some/random/path"
}
```

I know is possible with redirect but is not what I need.
I tried with regexp but doesn't seems to work

`@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{path:.*}`

There is any way to do that, or maybe some work arrounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2 workarounds here:

1. `@RequestMapping("/something/**")` and inject HttpServletRequest:
   `public MyCustomObj get(HttpServletRequest)` and manually parse path using `request.getServletPath()`
2. Do the same as above using custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. You could create custom annotation for this e.g. `@MyPath`:

   ```
   public class MyPathResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

       @Override
       public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
           return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(MyPath.class);
       }

       @Override
       public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
       NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
           return ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest().getServletPath().split("/")[2]; 
          //you can do whatever you want here, you can even get a value from your RequestMapping annotation 
            and customize @MyPath value as you want
       }
   }
   ```

Then you can inject your newly created annotation like this:
`public MyCustomObj get(@MyPath String path)`. Remember to register your argument resolver.